# Java scanner , taking specific part of string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Having typed the question and checked the similar title questions im gonna continue as I'm still not certain...

I have some traceroutes.. e.g.

```
14  t1tug.sunet.se (109.105.102.14)  48.394 ms  46.590 ms t1tug.sunet.se (109.105.102.18)  46.549 ms
15  t1fre-ae0-v1.sunet.se (130.242.83.37)  46.563 ms  46.087 ms m1tug-ae0-v1.sunet.se (130.242.83.42)  46.114 ms
16  m1fre-ae0-v1.sunet.se (130.242.83.50)  46.941 ms  44.270 ms  44.739 ms
17  uu-br1-xe-1-2-0.sunet.se (130.242.85.134)  47.494 ms  47.179 ms  45.662 ms
18  uu-g.sunet.se (193.11.0.234)  47.732 ms  44.848 ms  46.631 ms
19  PB-VSS.UU.SE (130.238.6.229)  48.695 ms  48.375 ms  46.407 ms
20  infoglue.uu.se (130.238.7.24)  50.402 ms  51.741 ms  52.465 ms
```

Using startswith I've cut my data so that only the lines starting with the number of the hop are going to be processed so I think I've simplified my problem.

Now all data from the first route to last have 4 characters before the name of the hop. I'm interested in just the name. Is there a simple way to take from the 5th character till the end of that part of the string?

i.e.

I just want "m1fre-ae0-v1.sunet.se"

This will be passed to a csv file. But I'm capable of that I just not sure about how I'd go about this. I've looked at regex but the format for the name does vary too much by my understanding of it. I would be happy to admit is weak.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two ways in my opinion:

1.Split your scanner string with " ". Then you'll have your desired string like this way:

```
String line = "14  t1tug.sunet.se (109.105.102.14)  48.394 ms  46.590 ms t1tug.sunet.se 109.105.102.18)  46.549 ms"
String splitted[] = line.trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(splitted[1]); //your desired string
```

Of course you'll need to put enough white spaces in .split() method

2.Use regular expressions to replace the string:

```
String line = "14  t1tug.sunet.se (109.105.102.14)  48.394 ms  46.590 ms t1tug.sunet.se (109.105.102.18)  46.549 ms";
String regexp = "^\\s*[0-9]+\s+([0-9A-Za-z\.\-]+)(.*)$";
line = line.replaceAll( regexp, "$1" );
System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: should regex should just be `\\s+` to split on whitespace.

Comment: yes this would work for the small set of nodes named following that regex but i was hoping for a solution that could take from 5th character to end of that part of that string to avoid writing multiple regex's. the one you suggested hits quite a few of the node names but unfortunately as i foresaw misses quite a few too.

Comment: yet again, made a small mistake, fixed it (for 2nd solution)
forgot to add \\- for other expressions :)
Now it should be OK for all examples you provided

Comment: ^ above was about regex implementation.

i like the look of the first split example. its certainly split it but the data isnt "numberOfHop  node" its " numberOfHop  node" with  white spaces first for the first 1-9. so its splitting the hop number for the 1-9 range and then doing correctly for the hobs later. i admit it was my fault for not giving a big enough data sample size in the first place for you to know this

Comment: @kamil it was hitting the nodes fine for my example but maybe i wasnt fully clear in my first message that the sample size is 18,000 lines. some of them are IPs for the node names. and some have longer node names than others so id guess using that implementation id need quite a few regex, thus me thinking the split would be the better implementation. im thinking i can just split it into 2 if statements split how u suggested for 10+ nodes and in the other if statement split differently, think im nearly there).

Comment: Could you provide some examples that not passed? We'll figure something out :) I fixed 2nd solution reg exp with possible white spaces at the beginning

Comment: As i say im liking/understanding split so it'd be nice to finish that. 10+ hops work as the double space is after the hop number. but just need to sort it so it does 0-9 where " no  " it needs to ignore first white space. ill add a full run to my first post so you can see what im on about

Comment: @user1290213 just do `line.trim().split("\\s+")` to trim the spaces at the beginning and end of the line.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I get it now after your edit, see my edited post. By the way, take your time and study regular expressions, it's really powerful tool

Comment: so close but yet so far, trim has got it working through to line 18,300 odd out of 18.750. But im getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 when trying to print it to screen around the 18,300 area. checking the log file i cant see why, formating wise it looks fine. the error message seems to be inside my printlns so im 100% sure which line. ill edit above and see if you have any ide as im so close :( thanks for the help so far.

Comment: i found the problem i just needed to write another if to deal with the lines that had just * on.